# Show second & third model level

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I kow this is known subject discussed but I'm not getting the issue solved.

This is my current app model design:

- Institution is the parent model of the app, which has many branches
- Branch model has a polymorphic relationship with Building model (child enttity)
- Classroom model belongs to Building model (1 Building, M Classroom)

I have a show.blade.php view where I list a Branch and I have 2 tabs for Buildings & Classrooms.

I can show each building for that branch but when I can' get to show all the classrooms in that branch (the relatioship is branch->building->classroom)

I have to solve this with a custom query in controller and then pass the result to the view or there is another approach?

Im trying to show classrooms from each institution ... but classrooms are related to builings.

```
 $a=App\Institution::find(1); //OK
 $a->branches; //OK
 $a->buildings; //OK
 $a->buildings->classrooms //Exception with message 'Property [classrooms] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Regards

**Institution Model**

```
public function branches()

    {
        return $this->hasMany(Branch::class);
    }

public function buildings()

    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Building', 'buildingable');
    }
```

**Branch Model**

```
public function institution()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Institution::class);
    }


public function buildings()

    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Building', 'buildingable');
    }
```

**Building Model**

```
public function buildingable()

{
    return $this->morphTo();
}


public function classrooms()

    {
        return $this->hasMany(Classroom::class);
    }
```

**Classroom Model**

```
public function building()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Building::class);
    }
```

**TABLE STRUCTURES**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('institutions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('inst_name', 30);
            $table->string('inst_id_type', 10);
            $table->string('inst_id_number', 10);
            $table->string('inst_country', 15);
            $table->string('inst_type', 15);
     });

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('branch_name', 30);
            $table->string('branch_id_type', 10);
            $table->string('branch_id_number', 10);
            $table->string('branch_country', 15);
            $table->string('branch_type', 15);
            $table->integer('institution_id');        
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('buildings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('building_name', 30);
            $table->integer('buildingable_id');
            $table->string('buildingable_type');
        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('classrooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('classroom_name', 20);
            $table->integer('building_id');
            $table->integer('employee_id'); 
        });
    }
```

Comment: would you provide some table structure? relations seems to be bit confusing (to me)!!

Comment: Yes sure @ab_in I will update the post

Comment: what do you have tried? where do you have error?

Comment: @ab_in , Im trying to show classrooms from each institution ... but classrooms are related to builings

>>> $a=App\Institution::find(1); // OK
>>> $a->branches; // OK
>>> $a->buildings; // OK
>>> $a->buildings->classrooms
Exception with message 'Property [classrooms] does not exist on this collection instance.'

Comment: what does your `$a->buildings`  returns? more than one record? did you loop the result and used `$building->classrooms` inside the loop?

Comment: $a->buildings returns one record ... I didn't loop $building->classrooms, how does it done in balde? Or loop has to be in controller?Thanks for your help!!

Comment: loop `$a->buildings` if needed. eg in blade: `@foreach($a->buildings as $building)  {{ dd($building) }} @endforeach` put the result to check pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a->buildings->classrooms` is the problem. `$a->buildings` is a collection, not an eloquent model. To get the classrooms of each building, you could use a `foreach` loop or the `each()` function on the connection.

`foreach` example:

```
foreach($a->buildings as $building) {
    $classrooms = $building->classrooms;
    // Do stuff here...
}
```

`each()` example:

```
$a->buildings->each(function ($building) {
    $classrooms = $building->classrooms;
    // Do stuff here...
}
```